# Difference of compounding interest question

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

I am trying to see how compounding interest and inflation affects purchasing power.

Let $x>y> n>1$. Does $x^n-y^n > (x-y+1)^n$   hold ?

Comment: If $x$ is close the $y$, the left-hand side is close to $0$ and the right-hand side is close to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider: $x = 3.00001$, $y = 3$, $n = 2$